# Storing variable values for particular time interval ,strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, timer, asp.net-4.0

I made a winform app in which i used a system.timers.timer control with a time interval of
             10 minutes , i declared a integer variable which gets incremented when a particular event is fired
             the issue is that integer value gets reset to 0 , but when i set timer control to 1 minute it shows the right result
             ,does anyone know why this strange behaviour ?

I did some resarch and found that one of the reason can be that
             garbage collector might be responsible for this , but int values are stored on heap ,right? which can not be GC'd until app domain is closed
             if u know any other solution then please advice , really needed this ? i think the issue is that variable is getting reset by GC ,but i also used ,GC.KeepAlive(TimerName);anyone please ?

Comment: Without code, this is unanswerable other than "almost certainly bugs in your code". Also, why is this tagged asp.net-4.0?

Comment: Code tells the best of stories..

Comment: People are more comfortable in reading code than a passage..

Comment: I agree with u guys ,actually code has lot of lines.. i just wanted to confirm that heap values are GC safe or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Timers.Timer` is a timer for multi-threaded environment.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The `Elapsed` event is raised on a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) thread.

Try to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead.
But if you are interested in a multi-threaded behaviour, set the timer's `SynchronizingObject` property to reference some object, which is declared in the same thread as your *integer variable*.